# Обучение при первом запуске приложения

Tags: android

Как можно сделать обучалку в приложении?

Например, фон затемняется, а нужный участок остается светлым и пишется подсказка, что как делать? Пробовал делать сам, почти получилось, но код вышел плохой.

Comment: Есть готовая библиотека [TourGuide](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide) полностью реализующая данный функционал

Comment: мне не совсем подходит, минимальная версия API 11, это много

Answer (score 3):

1. При запуске Проверяете `SharedPref` есть ли переменная `tutorial_pokazal` с значением `1` (так как в начале вы не писали, его нету)
2. показываете обучающее окно, хоть в этом окне хоть в другом `Activity`
3. Создаете переменную `tutorial_pokazal` со значением `1` и сохраняете в `SharedPref`

самый простой алгоритм

Comment: в как раз таки это я знаю, мне нужна именно сама обучалка, но все равно спасибо за помощь