# Подсказки наверх Activity

Tags: android

Ребята,видел во многих приложениях некие подсказки при первом вхождении в приложение.

Подсказки эти выгледят как поверх наложенные на активити прозрачные макеты, которые показывают мол вот сюда нажмёшь,туда попадёшь и т.д..

Как эти подсказки делаются,может есть какие примеры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри макета вашего активити, сделайте невидимый по умолчанию слой, с полупрозрачным фоном и подсказками. Потом показывайте его по событию или нажатию специальной инфо-кнопки.

В отличие от статичной картинки этот вариант хорош тем, что всегда видно актуальное состояние активити (на фоне за подсказками).

А если использовать `ConstraintLayout`, то можно даже попробовать привязать положение подсказок к конкретным элементам макета.

Answer (score 2):

Начните с этой библиотеки [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) - немного глючная, но если сильно не заморачиваться то работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данная библиотека работает,как я понимаю,прикриплением к определённому элементу,к примеру к кнопке.А если у меня есть элемент WebView,который прогружает сайт,собственно на котором мне и нужно сделать подсказки. Можно ли так сделать или нет?

Comment: Я думаю, что нет. К внутренностям `WebView` практически нет доступа - ну разве что есть несколько хуков типа: `onPageFinished()` и проч. По идее подсказки надо делать на сайте, а не на клиенте. Это все равно что пытаться из Windows стучаться к браузеру и рисовать поверх него что-то. Можно конечно, но как бы такой хакинг получается

Answer (score 0):

Уже были ответы [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455509/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
При использовании варианта с `SharedPref` лучше загружать отдельный activity с картинкой, чтобы не делать привязку к элементам и при этом ничего не плыло. Это самый очевидный из вариантов.

Comment: Там не описано как реализовать